# How do I get the last iteration of foreach if the total is unknown

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to echo a variable at the last iteration of a `foreach` loop, only counting when a conditional is met inside a loop.

I realize I could `echo $var` outside the `foreach` statement, but I'd really like to figure out a way to do this within the `foreach` statement. This a crude example where that makes total sense, but what I really want to do is figure out the last iteration within the `foreach` statement.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$var = "end";
foreach ($options as $option => $icon) {
     if (strpos($check[0], $option) !== false) {            
          echo $icon;
     }
     if (end($options)){
          echo $var;
     }                              
}
```

I have also tried setting up a counter  when `$icon` exists but nothing has worked correctly, because the total count is unknown.

How do I do this?

Comment: Put the `echo $var;` after the `}` that closed the foreach loop

Comment: @RiggsFolly I get that.  And I shouldn't have used a crude example where that makes total sense.  But what I really want to do is figure out how to figure out the last iteration within the foreach statement.

Comment: `end($options)` just returns the last element of the `$options` array, i.e. it will always `echo $var` (unless your `$options` array is empty, but in that case the whole `foreach()` won't run).

Comment: not sure about the use case for what you want to do, but you could use `array_key_last()` to achieve your goal - [demo](https://3v4l.org/T5AFe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array is not empty, `end` will always return the last element regardless of what element the array pointer is pointing to.

I don't see a valid reason for doing this, but you can just see if there is NOT a `next` element. `foreach` will advance the array pointer each iteration, so `next` will attempt to fetch the next one, and if it is on the last element it will fail:

```
$var = "end";
foreach ($options as $option => $icon) {
     if (strpos($check[0], $option) !== false) {            
          echo $icon;
     }
     if (!next($options)){
          echo $var;
     }                              
}
```